# how to add text view and image view on different views

Tags: ios

I have added view controllers according to my array count and set the content size of the horizontal scroll view.now i want some text to be displayed on each view.
for this i have taken a for loop but i'm not able to add text views over the views. 
this is my code:

```
   -(void)loadScrollView

{

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, scrollView.frame.size.height);

    NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < [_arrUrlLinks count]; i++) {

        [controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];

    }


 //   MyViewController1 *controller;

    self.viewControllers = controllers;
    // self.viewControllers =_txtView;
    count=1;


    // a page is the width of the scroll view

    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * [_arrUrlLinks count], scrollView.frame.size.height);

    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator =YES;

    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

    scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;

    scrollView.delegate = self;


    pageControl.numberOfPages = [_arrUrlLinks count];

    pageControl.currentPage = 0;

}





- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {

    if (page < 0) return;

    if (page >= [_arrUrlLinks count])

        return;


    controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];

    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {

        NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

        if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])

        {

            controller = [[MyViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController1" bundle:nil];

        }

        else{

           controller = [[MyViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController1_ipad" bundle:nil];

        }


       [controller initWithPageNumber: page];



        NSLog(@"loadscrollviewwithpage");

        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];


    }

    // add the controller's view to the scroll view

    if (nil == controller.view.superview) {

        CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;

        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;

        frame.origin.y = 0;

        controller.view.frame = frame;

               NSLog(@"111111%@",resultDicArray);

             NSLog(@"0000000%@",body);


        NSLog(@"header======.>>>>..%@",headerstr);




            } 



        [scrollView addSubview:controller.view]; 


    [self downLoadData:page]; 

}

- (void)unloadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page { 

    if (page < 0) return; 

    if (page >= [_arrUrlLinks count]) return; 


    controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page]; 



    if ((NSNull *)controller != [NSNull null]) { 

        if (nil != controller.view.superview) 

            [controller.view removeFromSuperview]; 



        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:[NSNull null]]; 

        NSLog(@"Unloadscrollviewwithpage"); 



    } 

} 



- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender { 

    if (pageControlUsed) { 


        return; 

    } 



    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width; 

    int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1; 

    pageControl.currentPage = page; 

    [self unloadScrollViewWithPage:page - 2]; 

    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:page - 1]; 

    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:page]; 

    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:page + 1]; 

    [self unloadScrollViewWithPage:page + 2]; 

    count=page+1; 


    // [self newCountTitleSet]; 

} 





- (void)viewDidLoad 
{ 

    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    [self loadScrollView];

     [self loadScrollViewWithPage:0];
     [self loadScrollViewWithPage:1];

}
```

i have successfully added my controllers over the scroll view now how to add text view over the controllers.

Comment: You need to ad different `UITextView` in different `controller` if you  need textview in all `controller`. Create a `UITextView` and add it as subview to `controller` after initialising `controller`.

Comment: when i add textviews as subview it is showing some exception: [__NSCFConstantString superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10013cfd0'

Comment: I've added a sample approach, you can try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
....

if (nil == controller.view.superview) {
    .....
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;

    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;

    frame.origin.y = 0;

    controller.view.frame = frame;

    //Add textview as subview to controller
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];

    textView.text = @"hello";

    textView.frame = //set frame here

    //set tag to textView if needed
    [controller.view addSubView:textView];

    [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
    NSLog(@"loadscrollviewwithpage................>>>>>>>>>>>>");
}

....
```

Comment: no this is not working.textview is not added on the view.but whenever i chane the view bt scrolling this log thing is printed.

Comment: Did you add `controller.view` to scrollview anywhere?

Comment: yes i have added [controller.view addSubview:textview]

Comment: I think you are not adding `controller.view` to `scrollView` by `[scrollView addSubview:controller.view];` after setting frame to it. Pls check the updated answer.

Comment: yes you were right i was missing this part of adding controller view to the scroll view.Now i'm not getting blank white color screen but a black color scroll view with the loader loading on it as if some data will be loaded but still i'm not getting the text view

Comment: Try setting `frame` and `backgroundColor` to `textView`. Also set `[controller.view bringSubViewToFront:textView];`

Comment: for(int j=1;j<=k;j++)
       {
            [controller.view addSubview:_txtView];
            _txtView.text = @"hello";
            
            _txtView.frame = CGRectMake(80,190,170,280);
           _txtView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            
            //set tag to textView if needed
            [controller.view addSubview:_txtView];
           _txtView.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
            [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
         

            
            NSLog(@"string to txt====");
      }
still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54254/discussion-between-akhilrajtr-and-pooja-1205).

Comment: have recognised some issue in the code can u please assist

Answer (score 1):

For example you want to 10 diffrent images or textview you could use this logic:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIScrollView *scr=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,  self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    scr.tag = 1;
    scr.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    [self.view addSubview:scr];
    [self setupScrollView:scr];
    UIPageControl *pgCtr = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 264, 480, 36)];
    [pgCtr setTag:12];
    pgCtr.numberOfPages=10;
    pgCtr.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    [self.view addSubview:pgCtr];
}


- (void)setupScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrMain {
    // we have 10 images here.
    // we will add all images into a scrollView &amp; set the appropriate size.

    for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
        // create image
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sti%02i.jpeg",i]];
        // create imageView
        UIImageView *imgV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i-1)*scrMain.frame.size.width, 0, scrMain.frame.size.width, scrMain.frame.size.height)];
        // set scale to fill
        imgV.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        // set image
        [imgV setImage:image];
        // apply tag to access in future
        imgV.tag=i+1;
        // add to scrollView
        [scrMain addSubview:imgV];


        UITextView*txtview =[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,50,200,200)];  
        [txtview setDelegate:self];    
        [txtview setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];    
        [txtview setTag:1];
        [txtview setText:[yourArray ObjectAtIndex:i]];
        [txtview setCornerRadius:5];    
        [scrMain addSubview:txtview];


    }
    // set the content size to 10 image width
    [scrMain setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrMain.frame.size.width*10, scrMain.frame.size.height)];


}
```